# pipe filepath one by one

Tags: bash, echo

I would like to **pipe** filename one by one at a time

my code:

```
echo src/content/* | sed -r 's/src\/content\///g' | xargs -n 1 -I {} node compile.js src/content/{} build/{}
```

Now `{}` means a lot of file paths, and this is not correct.

It should pipe file paths one by one, how should I do it?

---

my compile.js api:

```
node compile.js input_file output_file
```

Comment: Using `find` with `exec` would likely be what you want...

Answer (score 0):

With `find` you can achieve the same with something like this:

```
find src/content -type f -exec bash -c 'node compile.js $0 build/${0/#src\/content\//}' {} \;
```

`$0` is the `{}` i.e the input file and `${0/#src\/content\//}` cuts `src/content/` from its beginning.